# Include quotes in inline style

Tags: html, quotes

I have a class that I apply to a span to format it a bit different to show an action someone must take.

```
<p>Example of styling a <span style="background-color:#ccc; color:#066; font-weight:900; padding:0 8px;">Button</span> press.</p>
```

This example shows an inline style but it will eventually be in a class. What I want to know is is it possible to add angle brackets around the text as part of the styling? I know that `<q>` can achieve this but I want this to be part of the styling information. Is this possible in anyway.

Many thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can include brackets in your styles using pseudo-elements, it isn't supported by <= IE7 though (~4.5% market share last time I checked). This method uses pseudo-elements `:before` and `:after` to generate content based on CSS before and after the element respectively (while still remaining inside `.button`).

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/qqe9b/1/)

[image]

```
.button:before {
    content:"<";
}

.button:after {
    content:">";
}
```

Comment: That is perfect. Thank you very much. Just out of curiosity, am I right in thinking that pseudo-elements cannot be defined inline?

Many thanks

Comment: No you can't define them in your HTML, only in CSS. They are just like fake tags though so why wouldn't you just go with a `<span>` if you wanted to define it in HTML :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with the pseudo `:before` and `:after` and `content`.

```
span:before {
    content: "«";
}
span:after {
    content: "»";
}
```

I also think that this would be more appropriate as a [`kbd`](http://www.w3.org/community/webed/wiki/HTML/Elements/kbd) element.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExX66/